# Not able to import "package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart in for flutter project in android studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter

[Link to a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaKI8.png)I was trying to implement google sign in authentication in my Flutter project but it turns out that I am unable to import that above mentioned package.
I have already registered my app with firebase and also downloaded google services json file .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you imported the plugins to the pubspeck.yaml package? If not, take a look at [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages), the documentation for importing packages.

After knowing that, make sure to import [the google_sign_in package](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in).

The title and the plugin that you mention in the screenshot are different, so which one are you having trouble with?

Comment: I did not type the entire plug in in the editor as it was not suggesting anything

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and fixed it by running this command from the root directory of the flutter project:

$ flutter upgrade --force

This command gets the most recent version of the Flutter SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You need both [google_sign_in](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in) and [firebase_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth) packages in your pubspec.yaml file.
install both and follow the examples on the above links for more

Comment: Actually you can use google_sign_in package without firebase_auth one.

Answer (score -1):

If anyone still facing this issue. Simply just restart the VS code.